# Spring boot + Thymeleaf - Object with id null when editing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

When you select an Expense object from the data table for editing, the edit method in the controller sends the Expense object to the edit screen that is the same to insert a new record. When the object is sent to the save method, it has nullo code attribute where an insert occurs instead of an update. I do not understand why.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/despesas")
public class DespesaController {

    @Autowired private DespesaService despesaService;
    @Autowired private DespesaRepository despesaRepository;

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public ModelAndView novo(Despesa despesa) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("page/cadastro/despesa/cadDespesa");
        model.addObject("tiposDespesa", TipoDespesa.values());
        model.addObject("formasPagamento", FormaPagamento.values());
        model.addObject(despesa);
        return model;
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ModelAndView salvar(Despesa despesa, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return novo(despesa);
        }
        despesa.setDataDespesa(new Date());
        despesaService.salvarDespesa(despesa);
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", "Despesa Salva com Sucesso!");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/cadastroDespesa");
    }

    @GetMapping("/listDespesa")
    public ModelAndView listagemDeDespesas() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("page/cadastro/despesa/listDespesa");
        model.addObject("despesas", despesaRepository.findAll());
        return model;
    }

    @GetMapping("/edit{id}")
    public ModelAndView editar(@PathVariable("id") Long codigo) {
        return novo(despesaRepository.findOne(codigo));
    }
}
```

**FormEdit**

```
<form th:object="${despesa}" method="POST" th:action="@{/despesas/save}">
 <div class="box-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Data</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{dataDespesa}" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Valor</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{valor}" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Tipo Despesa</label> 
                    <select class="form-control select2" th:field="*{tipoDespesa}" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option th:each="tipo : ${tiposDespesa}" th:value="${tipo}" th:text="${tipo}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Forma Pagamento</label> 
                    <select class="form-control select2" th:field="*{formaPagamento}" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option th:each="forma : ${formasPagamento}" th:value="${forma}" th:text="${forma}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Observação</label> 
                <input type="text" th:field="*{observacao}" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
    <a class="btn btn-default" th:href="@{/}">Cancelar</a>
 </div>
</form>
```

**Data Table Where I select the object for editing**

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
        <th>Tipo Despesa</th>
        <th>Forma Pagamento</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="obj : ${despesas}">
        <td data-title="Data" th:text="${#calendars.format(obj.dataDespesa, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')}"></td>
        <td data-title="Valor" th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(obj.valor)}"></td>
        <td data-title="Tipo Despesa" th:text="${obj.tipoDespesa}"></td>
        <td data-title="Forma Pagamento" th:text="${obj.formaPagamento}"></td>
        <td><a th:href="@{/despesas/edit{id} (id=${obj.codigoDespesa})}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ${despesa.nova} ? @{/cadastroDespesa} : @{/despesa/edit{id} (id=${despesa.codigoDespesa})} This condition may be a problem. ${despesa.nova} may be getting evaluated to false hence the @{/despesa/edit{id} (id=${despesa.codigoDespesa}) may evaluated in the form, so when posted to this url there is no PostMapping method for that url in the Controller. Try to inspect ur Html and see what is the action url in the form.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I'll take the test and post the result

Comment: I corrected the error by adding a new method to my controller (I edited my question) but when I call the save method it is performing an insert instead of an update since I want to edit the object. Debugging the application I checked that the method is receiving the data table object with the null code, I do not understand why.

Comment: What do mean by null code.??? Put your Entity object here. If u are using hibernate check whether @Id attribute is set. Becoz hibernate/JPA decides to insert/update the data depending on this Id field.

Comment: In the new method that I added in my controller named EditSave, the Expense Object is arriving with the NullFont attribute, which is the primary key column of my table in the database. The attribute is noted correctly. This problem does not occur when you call the edit method on the controller.

Comment: I edited my controller. 
When you select an Expense object from the data table for editing, the edit method in the controller sends the Expense object to the edit screen that is the same to insert a new record. When the object is sent to the save method, it has nullo code attribute where an insert occurs instead of an update. I do not understand why.

Comment: I dont see any expense field in your EditForm. U need to keep that in the form if the form has to post back on submit. Try keeping a text(or a hidden if u dont want that to display) field in the EditForm and populate that with the Primary key value in the html. So that when the user edits and submits the form the hidden id value will be binded to the object and the record in the db will be updated.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the help, it's all right now, I've added the following input to my form: <input type = "hidden" th: field = "* {codigoDespesa}" />.
It was an apprenticeship, I did not think that would be it.

Answer (score 1):

As sr.praneeth said you need to add the fields you want to populate into the form, usually the ID are not visible but you need to send them.

```
<form th:object="${despesa}" method="POST" th:action="@{/despesas/save}">
 <div class="box-body">
 <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
 ...  
 </form>
```

Then in your Controller you will be able to retrieve the id value, null if its a creation, or informed if its an update